# Recreating Object from text file when that Object holds a variable of another object - Java

Tags: java

Sorry if the subject is misleading, was not overly sure how to word this but anyway here goes. 
I have to recreate a List of books that have been written out to a .txt file. I have no problem reading in the primitive data types these books hold and then recreating the object using the object constructor and these details but, the book object also holds an object reference of "Member" which is passed in when said Member borrows said book. (who also store an ArrayList of Book objects for books they borrow).

So my problem is, I cannot recreate one without the other being already recreated. I get the feeling there is some easy way of doing this that my beginner mind doesn't get, but I truly feel stumped as to how i should handle this.

No code is really needed, just a general response would be nice to point me in the right direction, I subscribe to the idea of doing it yourself and failing a bunch of times to really learn, only problem here is I really don't know where to start.

EDIT: Some code provided in the comments

```
private String bookNumber; 
private String title; 
private String author; 
private int loanPeriod; 
private boolean availability; 
private Member borrower; 

'Those are the variables that the Book object holds, 
'and when written to .txt look like this 
Book VAM-001 Dracula Stoker, B 14 true null
```

Comment: A bit of code would be nice though as it oftentimes clarifies a quetion. (:

Comment: I don't know how much I should put up as it is part of an Assignment but,

Comment: private String bookNumber;
 private String title;
 private String author;
 private int loanPeriod;
 private boolean availability;
 private Member borrower;

Those are the variables that the Book object holds, and when written to .txt look like this

Book
VAM-001
Dracula
Stoker, B
14
true
null
(sorry for the formatting)

Comment: The problem of circular references is well-known and handled out of the box by Java's built-in serialization. The basic idea is that when you first write out an object instance, you assign it a unique id. The next time you need to write out the same object instance, you only write something that says "use object with id X".

Comment: Cod ein comments is useless.  Please edit it into the question itself.

Comment: The other option, also available in your case (but not in general) is to exploit the fact that the list of borrowed books stored by `Member` and the borrower reference stored by `Book` are two sides of the same coin: if you store one, you can reconstruct the other from it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to cycle it two times.

In first cycle, you create objects with all references to non-primitive types set to null. In second cycle, you associate it with concrete values.